# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el estado planificador de eventos siempre esté activo? phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una duda con respecto al estado de planificador de eventos, estoy usando el phpMyAdmin localmente y cada que inicio el servidor y la base de datos con XAMPP el estado planificador de eventos se desactiva, siempre será así o cómo podría solucionarlo? Pasa que con ello desactivo los eventos y no se ejecutan y, en mi caso, tengo eventos que corresponden al tiempo máximo de sesión y demás.

[image: Estado planificador de eventos]

> No tiene nada que ver, pero dejo el evento del cierre de sesión que se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo.

```
DELETE FROM tablaSesiones WHERE tablaSesiones.inicioSesion IS NOT NULL AND
NOW() >= DATE_ADD(tablaSesiones.inicioSesion, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que el "Planificador de eventos" siempre inicie activo, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Buscar el archivo `my.ini` dentro del directorio de `XAMPP`
  Ejemplo:

  ```
  xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
  ```
- Agregar:

  ```
  [mysqld]
  event_scheduler=ON
  ```

  *Nota: Puede que `[mysqld]` ya exista, en tal caso agregar solo la línea `event_scheduler=ON` debajo.*
- Guardar el archivo.
- Reiniciar el servicio de `MySQL`.

Comment: Lo he probado y me ha funcionado, muchas gracias! Una consulta extra, cuando esto lo suba a un host (la configuración que acabo de hacer en el `my.ini`) cómo podría asegurarme de que seguirá estando activo el estado planificador de eventos?

Comment: Si en tu host tenes acceso al my.ini, realizas los mismos cambios y listo

Comment: Genial, gracias, me ha quedado más claro